# Can't access static methods in Eloquent (used outside Laravel)

Tags: php, methods, orm, static, eloquent

I've followed Jeffrey Way's explanation and several other blog posts and articles, yet still cannot get this to work.

I want to use the Eloquent ORM outside of Laravel. I've included the requirements in my `composer.json`:

```
"illuminate/database": "v5.*",
"illuminate/events": "v5.*",
```

Then I instantiated the Capsule Manager:

```
$db = new Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager();
$db->addConnection($config['database']);
$db->setEventDispatcher(new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher(new Illuminate\Container\Container));
$db->setAsGlobal();
$db->bootEloquent();
```

I've built a basic User model that extends the Eloquent Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'username';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

Now I can create a new User as intended:

```
$u = new User([
    'username' => $username,
    'fullname' => $fullname,
    'role_id'  => $role_id,
]);
$u->save();
```

And this works like a charm, the user appears in the intended `users` table fine, yet I can't retrieve a user by any of these methods, my response is always `null`:

```
$user = User::find('foo'); // no dice
$user = User::where('username', 'foo')->get(); // nope
$user = User::first(); // nothing
```

Does anyone know why I can't use the static methods that come with Eloquent models? Or better yet, how to fix this?